# Docker dns failure

Tags: dns, docker

I launched [Concourse CI worker](http://concourse.ci/) with Boot2docker on OS X.

Docker info:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:13:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 19:36:04 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

When I tried to build docker image I had a problem.

Build instruction:

```
- put: docker-registry
  params:
    build: src-develop
    tag: version/version
```

Build log:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  80.9 kB
Step 1 : FROM python:3.5
Pulling repository docker.io/library/python
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/python/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:59668->127.0.0.11:53: read: connection refused
```

Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your docker cannot connect to internet. If you're behind a proxy, you need to restart docker with proxy settings.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#/http-proxy

Next, add proxy ENVIRONMENT to your Dockerfile.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179301/how-do-you-run-apt-get-in-a-dockerfile-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with a recent Docker version 1.13.1 and Concourse 2.6. Not sure what the actual cause is, but a workaround was to set other DNS server for the worker container.
The hint was given to me in this compose example: https://gist.github.com/colthreepv/6b818cfcf296dc1b5c2cf15eb76a140e

Answer (score 0):

You should give Docker a DNS server by providing the `--dns` flag, there are many public permanent DNS servers you can use:

```
1.1.1.1
4.2.2.2
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
9.9.9.9
```